# How to connect JProfiler to Virgo Server running in remote linux machine

Tags: jprofiler, eclipse-virgo

Please help me how to connect **JProfiler** from windows machine to remote **Virgo Jetty Server** which is running in linux server.

Below are the steps I am following

1. From Choose Integration Wizard selecting Eclipse Virgo(Next)
2. Then I am selecting option of on remote computer with Linux platform(Next)
3. Then I am selecting JVM vendor Version etc (Next)
4. selecting option Wait or a connection from JProfiler GUI(Next)
5. Providing remote hostname:port(Next)
6. I was stuck at specifying remote installation directory

Here we didnt install JProfiler in our linux remote environment but we have server running there.I have seen option like If JProfiler is not installed,you can create archive and that contains profiling agent and extractit in above directory.Asking folder where to create Archive.

Can you please help what exactly this means what I need to do to create archive .Only thing I have done is installed JProfiler evaluation version in local machine and profiling local server.

Please help and let me know any additional information is required..Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

If you select the option to create an archive in the integration wizard, JProfiler will create a .tar.gz file that contains the libraries for the profiling agent. You transfer that archive to the Linux server and extract it somewhere, e.g. to `/home/myname/jprofiler` by calling

```
mkdir /home/myname/jprofiler
cd /home/myname/jprofiler
tar xzvf /path/to/jprofiler_agent_linux-x64.tar.gz
```

In the integration wizard, specify `/home/myname/jprofiler` as the remote installation directory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, After providing the remote linux machine path for downloading tar.gz file .Initially I get option for downloading native libraries in linux machine.As soon as I click for download of native libraries I get below error THERE WAS ERROR DOWNLOADING NATIVE LIBRARIES.
Could you please suggest on this.Is there a way we can download native libraries(.tar.gz) file in local machine(Windows) so that we can copy it manually to linux server.
Also can you please tell where we provide exact virgo instance(startup.sh) as we are having two virgo instances running in remote linux server.